# Can I use C-style casts when calling C functions from C++?

Tags: c++, type-casting

I have read, both [on this site](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/50442/c-style-casts-or-c-style-casts) and elsewhere, that the recommended programming style for C++ is to avoid using C-style casts, and prefer the C++-style `static_cast`, `dynamic_cast`, `reinterpret_cast`, and `const_cast`. The reasons for this recommendation generally boil down to (1) the C++ casts are safer because they are more specific and limited in meaning, and (2) they are intentionally verbose and ugly because you should not be using them often in good C++ code. However, this reasoning doesn't make as much sense when it comes to calling C functions from my C++ code.

In my C++ projects I am often forced to call OS-level libraries that only have a C interface, such as the POSIX sockets library for network operations. These C functions often expect the caller to make several pointer casts, and if I stick to only C++-style casts my code becomes clunky and verbose. For example, my networking code is littered with function calls like this:

```
std::size_t message_size;
ssize_t bytes_read = recv(fd, reinterpret_cast<char*>(&message_size), sizeof(message_size), MSG_WAITALL);
```

I'm not gaining any safety from using C++ casts (since `reinterpret_cast` doesn't really add any more compile-time checks than a C-style cast), and the ugliness of the code isn't alerting me to a problem - there's no way to use socket functions without casting.

In light of the interface mismatch between C and C++, would it be reasonable to use C-style casts when calling C functions that require casting? Or are C-style casts always bad practice, and I should just accept the extra code bloat when I need to call C functions?

Comment: For interop with C code I often just use C-style casts... not ideal practice, but whatever -- I'd rather spend my time focusing on writing tests for correctness than trying to find ways to do bulletproof type casts when communicating with a C lib. One argument maybe I could offer in favor of using C-style casts in this context is that it enriches the meaning of C++ casts elsewhere in the codebase.. Communicating with C APIs can require a boatload of casting, and if you sprinkle your code with `static_casts` here and `reinterpret_casts` there, you end up polluting...

Comment: ... your searches for cases where you're performing casts in C++ code that isn't interacting with a C library, where the casts should be few and far between. There are very few reasons for C++ code calling C++ code to have to cast, so it might help to reserve the C++ casts for those cases and make them stick out instead of obscured by a boatload of casts required for C++ code to work with C code. So that might be one argument, but TBH I just find it ugly in this context and I've never found the use of a `static_cast` or `reinterpret_cast` to ever prevent problems, e.g., over a C-style cast.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's easy to prevent the verbosity of calling C functions from cluttering your code: wrap them. In the case of `recv`, for example, you can simply do this:

```
template <typename T>
ssize_t recv(int fd, T& data) {
  return ::recv(fd, reinterpret_cast<char*>(&data), sizeof(data), MSG_WAITALL);
}
```

You can improve on this by e.g. `static_assert`ing that `T` is trivially copyable or has some other desired properties.

Now if you use this function instead of the C `recv` all over the code, you have reduced clutter and improved safety (you can't accidentally mismatch the data type and its size).

At the same time, you're still using C++-style casts, which prevents you from accidentally casting away constness.

Answer (score 4):

The standard explains how the C style cast works (N4296):

> **5.4/4:** The conversions performed by
>
> - a `const_cast`,
> - a `static_cast`,
> - a `static_cast` followed by a `const_cast`,
> - a `reinterpret_cast` , or
> - a `reinterpret_cast` followed by a `const_cast`,
>
> can be performed using the cast notation of explicit type conversion.
>   (...)

Without entering into the details, the rest of the paragraph also explains that the C cast relaxes some constraints that would apply to `static_cast` in presence of pointers to derived classes.  This relaxed attitude is one of the reasons why it is advised not to use it in C++ code.

In your case, using  `(char*)&message_size` would result in `reinterpret_cast<char*>(&message_size)` to be generated by the compiler.  So you wouldn't lose anything by using `reinterpret_cast` directly.

Bjarne Stroustrup gives a couple of other reasons, why the C++ casting should be preferred in his book "*The design and evolution of C++*":

> To sum up, old-style cast:
>
> 1. Are a problem for understanding: they provide a single notation for several weakly related operations
> 2. Are error-prone: almost every type combination [i.e. source type and target type] has a legal interpretation
> 3. Are hard to spot in code and hard to find with simple tools
> 4. Complicate the C and C++ grammars
>
> The new cast operators represent a classification of the old's cast
>   functionality.

Of course, in your special case, point 1, 2 and 4 are not a real issue.  Nevertheless using the new style would bring you the benefit of point 3, and would get you used to the greater precision that is commonly used in C++ casting.

On the other side, IMHO, it would not be shocking to still use the C syntax if you restrict its use to the sole highlight in the code the interoperability with the C libraries.

Comment: I feel like saying point 1,2 and 4 do not matter in his case is a bit short-sighted. Looking at a correctly written snipped in isolation and state that the two ways are equivalent to the compiler is not an argument. If he had expected to be able to convert a primitive with static cast the compiler error would still have hinted him there was something is wrong in his reasoning. The compiler would still catch const - correctness issues. The reinterpret_cast still gives more information to the reader. Those points still stand. Apart from that, your answer still makes perfect sense though.